# UnBlock mixed content in Next.js

Tags: next.js, next.js13, mixed-content

I request data from a http source and there is no way getting it from a https source. The problem is that every request gets blocked.

Is there a way to ALLOW mixed content in Next.js, using the fetch function with a descriptor in the option of the fetch request? btw I'm hosting it on vercel.com